# Only draw shapes within a boundary in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have this example here: https://editor.p5js.org/agjones91/sketches/v6N5UlCAz

The code is simple, create 100 circles in random locations with a square on top. What I need to do is crop the circles to only show them inside the square. The parts of the circles outside of the square can not show.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noFill();
  translate(100, 100);
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var circleX = random(2, 50);
    var circleY = random(2, 50);

    circle(circleX, circleY, 100);
  }
  stroke("red");
  square(-25, -25, 100); //cop using this square
}
```

Once this is done, I'd need to repeat it a number of times across the canvas so overlaying shapes to cover the outside can't be used. I need the circles to not draw outside a certain boundary.

Comment: maybe using graphics? https://p5js.org/examples/structure-create-graphics.html

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia that worked, ill add the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this thanks to @Alberto Sinigaglia in the comments above and the user of graphics: https://editor.p5js.org/agjones91/sketches/v6N5UlCAz

The idea is to apply the circles to one layer (graphic) and then crop (mask) this out using another layer. See code below:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  img = createGraphics(width, height);
  img.noFill(); //apply styles to new graphics layer
  img.translate(100, 100); //apply translations to new graphics layer
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var circleX = random(2, 50);
    var circleY = random(2, 50);
    img.ellipse(circleX, circleY, 100, 100); //apply shapes to new graphics layer
  }

  mk = createGraphics(width, height);
  mk.translate(75, 75);
  mk.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);

  imgClone = img.get();
  imgClone.mask(mk.get());

  image(imgClone, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solved the same issue I had!